# Regular time to decimal time in Python

Tags: python, time

How can I convert any regular time(24:60:60) into decimal one(10:100:100) in Python?

I’ve tried to use hours = hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600, but it’s actually not the result I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
decimal_seconds=seconds/0.864 + minutes/0.0144 +hours/0.00024
print(f'{int(decimal_seconds//10000)}:{int((decimal_seconds%10000)//100)}:{int(decimal_seconds%100)}')
```

Comment: Do you want 0.864 instead of 0.862?

Comment: Yes it should be 0.864